# Slow down setAttribute()

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to slow down a setAttribute()? For example, I have the following code:

```
function hide(i) {
    var previewDiv = document.getElementById('preview');
    var fullDiv = document.getElementById('full');
    previewDiv.setAttribute('style', 'display:normal;');
    fullDiv.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
}
```

Now want to make the display:none go to display:normal with a delay so it "fades" open instead of just bluntly open. Or is there another good way to achieve this?

Comment: No, there's no way to do that, you have to create functions that constantly updates the opacity to create a fading effect, or you could just use CSS transitions to animate it.

Comment: You could use jQuery or something like that to animate this without too much effort. [link to jQuery Hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in a multitude of ways. You could use jQuery's fadeIn method `$('.element').fadeIn();` or using css and Javascript. I found this example http://www.chrisbuttery.com/articles/fade-in-fade-out-with-javascript/ by Chris Buttery.

I really comes down to taste. Although one could argue that the second option should be more optimal on most systems.